# Обработка исключений Excepions Java

Tags: java, исключения

Только прошел эту тему по исключениям на курсах. Подскажите пожалуйста в решении такой задачи, а именно в обработке исключений.
В метод на ввод задается двумерный стринговый массив размером 4х4. Нужно посчитать сумму его элементов. Если размер массива не 4х4 нужно выбросить исключение ArraySizeException (делаем его сами). Элементы стрингового массива представлены цифрами для превращения их в инт методом Integer.parseInt.
Если в массиве другой символ - нужно выкинуть другое исключение  ArrayDataException (тоже нужно сделать его самому, и в сообщении указать ячейку где задан не правильный символ) - как это сделать ?
Так же при вводе не правильного символа выбрасывается стандартное исключение NumberFormatException - как его одработать ?
Вот мой код :
метод :

```
 static int doCalc(String[][] matrix) {
        if (matrix.length != 4 ) throw new ArraySizeException(" Make matrix size 4x4");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
               sum += Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

И в мейне :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        result = doCalc(new String[][] {{"1", "a", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
    } catch (ArraySizeException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        result = doCalc(new String[][] {{"1", "a", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
}catch (ArrayDataException exception){
    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    result = doCalc(new String[][] {{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
}
System.out.println(" Sum = " + result);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, почему вас загнал в ступор NumberFormatException , если вы ниже пишете код, обрабатывающий исключения? Да, он обрабатывает ваши исключения, но какая разница? NumberFormatException подчиняется таким же правилам, как и все остальные исключения.

Кроме того, для проверки того, что массив действительно имеет размер 4х4 неплохо бы контролировать две длины матрицы , а не одну, ведь это двухмерный массив, единственным вызовом метода length здесь не отделаешься.

Если вы не понимаете , в чем именно проблема проверки длины, которую выполнили вы, прочитайте про так называемые "лохматые матрицы". Ели в двух словах, то ожидаемая вами матрица (4х4), должна выглядеть так:

1234

1234

1234

1234

Но не забывайте, что в Джаве возможно создание, к примеру, такой матрицы:

1234

123

12

1234

В итоге попробуйте сделать примерно так:

```
static int doCalc(String[][] matrix) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix.length != 4 || matrix[i].length != 4) throw new ArraySizeException("Make matrix size 4x4");
            try {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][j]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ArrayDataException("Incorrect array's data : " + i + " - " + j);
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

и теперь метод мейн:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //пробуем с заведомо некорректным размером массива
    try {
        int result = doCalc(new String[][]{{"1", "a", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
        System.out.println(result);    
    } catch (ArraySizeException | ArrayDataException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    //пробуем с заведомо некорректными данными в массиве
    try {
        int result = doCalc(new String[][]{{"1", "a", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
        System.out.println(result);        
    } catch (ArraySizeException | ArrayDataException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());            
    }

    //пробуем корреткные данные
    try {
        int result = doCalc(new String[][]{{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
        System.out.println(result);        
    } catch (ArraySizeException | ArrayDataException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());            
    }
    
}
```

Не стесняйтесь задавать вопросы, если что-то непонятно

Comment: Спасибо вам больщое за помощь. Но как теперь будет в мейне ? Я хочу добиться результата суммы элементов после обработки исключений . А у меня даже не выводится сообщение из ArrayDataException. Что я сделал не так :

Comment: try {
            result = doCalc(new String[][] {{"1", "a", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
        } catch (ArraySizeException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           result = doCalc(new String[][] {{"1", "a", "3", "4"}, {"5", "6", "7", "8"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}, {"9", "10", "11", "12"}});
        }catch (ArrayDataException arrayDataException){
           arrayDataException.printStackTrace();
           result = doCalc(new String[][] - уже исправленый масив

Comment: @Artur вы точно читали теорию по этой теме? в вашем методе мейн только один блок try, в котором программа ожидает исключение. как только вы попали в блок catch вы одновременно вышли из области действя try. но в вашем блоке catch снова вызывается метод doCalc() с некорретными данными, а значит из метода doCalc() снова прилетит исключение, которое уже никто не ловит, ведь вы за пределами блока try , вы в блоке catch. посмотрите мой ответ, я его дополнил и перечитайте теорию

Comment: Нам объяснали что можно изменять данные как бы на ходу прямо в блоке catch, изменяя на корректные данные . Может я что-то не допонял.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь )

Comment: @Artur вам объяснили, что в блоке catch можно изменять данные на корректные, а не на любые! а вы что сделали? вы в блоке catch воткнули некорреткный массив. это примерно тоже самое, что на автомобиль натянули квадратные колеса, он не прошел тест и их поменяли на треугольные. он одинаково не едет. вы в "ремонтном блоке" выполнили кривой ремонт))

Comment: Отличная аналогия )) Теперь стало на много яснее ! Еще раз вам спасибо ) Это тоже очень важно для обучения - получить разъяснения от опытного джависта, потому что преподаватель на курсе объясняет на элементарных примерах, а на практике задания на много сложнее.